# ZF2 plural translator, why an array?

Tags: php, zend-framework2, zend-translate

In `zf2` you have the view helper [`translatePlural`](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/modules/zend.i18n.view.helpers.html#translateplural-helper) . Which can be use as followed;

```
echo $this->translatePlural('car', 'cars', $num);
```

So when `$num == 1` it says `car` else `cars` (depending on the plural rule but for now use the english rule).

To translate this, by file. You have to use an array like;

```
'car' => [
  'auto',
  'autos',
],
```

So now you get `auto` if `$num == 1` else `autos`.

If you have some where else in your code to translate `car` you could do `translate('car')` but that will return to a notice `array to string coverstion`, which is obvious not what we want.

So to be able to also translate just `car` and use the plural I now have to modify the code to something like;

```
echo $this->translatePlural('car_plural', 'cars', $num);
```

And the language config;

```
'car_plural' => [
  'auto',
  'autos',
],
'car' => 'auto',
```

And you need to have to add an english translation for `car_plural`. So the `translatePlural` default messages become prety much useless in a default setup, unless you use `translatePlural` not for translation but for just to choose between `car` or `cars` and not translating it.

But if instead the `translatePlural` just looked at `$num` then use the `pluralRule` to choose between singular (car) or plural (cars). Then use the `translate` helper to translate the singular or plural, you can have an easy config like and the default message all of sudden work again;

```
'car' => 'auto',
'cars' => 'autos',
```

No weird keys, you don't need english translation's or something else weird.

So the question /tldr;

**Why does ZF2 plural uses an array and not just check which one to use and translate that one? Seems to me a way better method.**

Comment: Take a look at this discussion: https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/issues/4939

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I, too, was baffled by this. After some assistance from a coworker and a lot of research, I found that there was a sound architectural reason for this. (I know! I'm surprised, too!)

It turns out that some languages have a different definition of singular vs plural. Some only have 1 form that serves as both singular and plural, and others have 3 or more plural forms.

The translatePlural method can't satisfy these other language forms, so instead it references the Gettext way of handling this. In a gettext file, plural translations for English are handled like this:

```
msgid "Found %d Result"
msgid_plural "Found %d Results"
msgstr[0] "Found %d Result"
msgstr[1] "Found %d Results"
```

So the singular/plural values are used to look up the array by the msgid, and then the language's plural index is used to choose either msgstr[0] or msgstr[1].

In a language that has 3 plural forms, the localization would look like this:

```
msgid "Found %d Result"
msgid_plural "Found %d Results"
msgstr[0] "singular translation"
msgstr[1] "plural translation"
msgstr[2] "super plural translation"
```

So this is why Zend uses an array, and why just flipping between $singular and $plural is insufficient. (I posted a version of this answer on my blog, but I don't know if it's kosher to link blogs in answers)